# Adjust adjust time in by adding seconds for both remote location and current location with pytz & datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pytz, python-datetime

I'm trying to add some seconds onto a time but I can't find how to do it at all.

```
add_seconds = 952
cur_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).strftime("%H%M")
```

The code above is what I am using to get a current, correct time for London, UK and I am trying to add `add_seconds` onto it which should give me a different time to the current time in London

If I can convert the `cur_time` then I can do what I need to do by:

```
cur_time =+ add seconds
m, s = divmod(cur_time, 60)
h, m = divmod(m, 60)
print "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
```

However, I would also want to print the adjusted local time of where the script is being ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean using `datetime.timedelta`?

```
import datetime
import pytz

add_seconds = datetime.timedelta(seconds=952)
cur_time = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
cur_time += add_seconds

print(cur_time)
```

This way you end up with a new `datetime.datetime` object with the extra time added in.